# single.php date wrong although right declaration

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

a Wordpress installation shows the wrong date on the single.php sites.

On the front-end the user will currently see something like this under the article:

> 30. November -0001

The article with the date shown above was posted on the 17th July 2015.
The date is implemented with usage of the "the_date" tag from the Wordpress codex.

```
<?php the_date('d. F Y'); ?>
```

I don't know what could possibly cause this problem.

Thanks for every comment!

Comment: What is the result of `echo $wp_query->posts[0]->post_date;`

Comment: The Result is: 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Even in the wp-admin the dates are right.

Comment: Are you using `query_posts` somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this inside loop:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php echo get_the_date('j F Y'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```